# scope of callback in a .connect() (nodejs, mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

im trying to use a global database object to handle the data on my nodejs server. It shall contain all data of all connected users. Ready to be accessed anytime out of ram.

Therefore i created a module:

```
function Database() {
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
this.dbcon; //database connection

// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname", this.givedatabasevars);
};
```

As i want to reuse the database connection instead of opening new ones everytime i want to access the propertys of my object using the callback function and give them the connection object:

```
Database.prototype.givedatabasevars = function(err, getdbcon) {
if(err) {console.log(err)};
this.dbcon = getdbcon; //not working(scoped changed when used as callback?)
db.dbcom = getdbcon; //also not working(db object maybe not there yet as its a callback in constructor?)

};
```

I create the object using this globaly:

```
var Database = require('./node_modules/database/database.js');
var db = new Database();
```

Now im pretty new to nodejs and javascript all together. I tryed to get my head around how to access the objects scope, but from within the callback i cant even access the global scope.

Is this even possible? 
Its the same for what to do with the data when using .find() with a callback. How do i get the data out of there to be used by my application? I need to store it, not to use it directly.

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

You can access the global object using the `global` variable. Do `console.log(this)` on a plain file to see all the globals.

And for `mongodb` maybe [mafintosh/mongojs](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs) can give you a more shareable interface. In fact I think with that you don't even need to have a global necessarily ;)